# Javascript check if the result of a function has been already outputted and if yes, run the function

Tags: javascript, function

I apologize in advance for my bad english.

I made a javascript function `gen()` that generate a value by adding two values randomly selected from two arrays.

I want to make a function that run `gen()` and that outputs the value only if it has never been outputted before, else would perform the function `gen()` again.

Thanks in advance.

The code of the `gen()` function:

```js
function gen() {
  var s = ["a", "b"];
  var c = ["c", "d"];

  var MbSubj = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"];
  var MaSubj = ["John", "Jack", "Matt"];
  var FbSubj = ["Lara", "Juliet"];
  var FaSubj = ["Lora", "Elise"];

  var sRand = s[Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length)];
  var cRand = c[Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length)];
  var FbSubjRand = FbSubj[Math.floor(Math.random() * FbSubj.length)];
  var MbSubjRand = MbSubj[Math.floor(Math.random() * MbSubj.length)];
  var FaSubjRand = FaSubj[Math.floor(Math.random() * FaSubj.length)];
  var MaSubjRand = MaSubj[Math.floor(Math.random() * MaSubj.length)];

  function mb() {
    return MbSubjRand + MaSubjRand;
  }

  function ma() {
   return MaSubjRand + MbSubjRand;
  }

  function fb() {
    return FbSubjRand + MaSubjRand;
  }

  function fa() {
    return FaSubjRand + MbSubjRand;
  }

  if (sRand === "a" && cRand === "b") {
    mb();
  } else if (sRand === "b" && cRand === "c") {
    ma();
  } else if (sRand === "a" && cRand === "d") {
    fb();
  } else {
    fa();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the whole function to run only once, or each name combination to appear only once?

Comment: Each name combination to appear only once

Comment: The gen function run every time i press a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in variable, if you already run **gen**, if yes, not run in again, if not, run it:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0j8wqswn/

```
function gen(){
    alert('this is the gen function')
}


(function(){
    var alreay_run=false;
    new_function=function(){
        if(alreay_run) return
        alreay_run=true
        gen();
    }
})()


//Let's Test
new_function()
new_function()
new_function()

//You will see alert only one time
```